# ASP.NET add html button click event

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have to add html button click event in asp.net.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Logout" class="btn btn-link">
<em class="fa fa-sign-out text-muted"></em>
</button>
```

I'm using html button here because I have to place this outside of the asp.net form(runat server) tag. So I can't use link button here. The second thing is I have to use icon as button. So if there is any other methods to accomplish both of this tasks please suggest them also.

Comment: You can achieve this task using onclick javascript event along with ajax script.

Comment: can you give me a sample please

Comment: When doing Web Forms Development, I typically have my form just inside the body. Then you can use your server controls anywhere you want.

Comment: Yes. But here I cannot do that

Comment: If it is outside the form with `runat=server`... then just wrap the button in its own form that posts to whatever page you want. You don't need a standard 'click' event function. Just pass a hidden form variable, and then on the page you post to, if that variable exists, run your function.

Answer (score 0):

In html button:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Logout" class="btn btn-link" onclick="runLogout()">
<em class="fa fa-sign-out text-muted"></em>
</button>
```

In javascript file:

```
var xmlHttp = null;

function getXmlHttp() {
    try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e) {
                alert(e.description);
            }
        }
    }
}

function runLogout() {
    getXmlHttp();

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    // ... your code here ...
                }

                return;
            }
        };

    xmlHttp.open("POST", "Logout.aspx", true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```